# Training the OpenCV NormalBayesClassifier in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use the NormalBayesClassifier to classify images produced by a Foscam 9821W webcam.  They're 1280x720, initially in colour but I'm converting them to greyscale for classification.

I have some Python code (up at http://pastebin.com/YxYWRMGs) which tries to iterate over sets of ham/spam images to train the classifier, but whenever I call train() OpenCV tries to allocate a huge amount of memory and throws an exception.

```
mock@behemoth:~/OpenFos/code/experiments$ ./cvbayes.py --ham=../training/ham --spam=../training/spam
Image is a <type 'numpy.ndarray'> (720, 1280)
...
*** trying to train with 8 images
responses is [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 6794772480020 bytes) in OutOfMemoryError, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp, line 52
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cvbayes.py", line 124, in <module>
    classifier = cw.train()
  File "./cvbayes.py", line 113, in train
    classifier.train(matrixData,matrixResp)
cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:52: error: (-4) Failed to allocate 6794772480020 bytes in function OutOfMemoryError
```

I'm experienced with Python but a novice at OpenCV so I suspect I'm missing out some crucial bit of pre-processing.

Examples of the images I want to use it with are at https://mocko.org.uk/choowoos/?m=20130515.  I have tons of training data available but initially I'm only working with 8 images.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong to make the NormalBayesClassifier blow up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually found the problem - I was using NormalBayesClassifier wrong.  It isn't meant to be fed dozens of HD images directly: one should first munge them using OpenCV's other algorithms.

I have ended up doing the following:
 + Crop the image down to an area which may contain the object
 + Turn image to greyscale
 + Use cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack() to collect features from the cropped area to train the classifier.

A tiny number of features works for me, perhaps because I've cropped the image right down and its fortunate enough to contain high-contrast objects that get obscured for one class.

The following code gets as much as 95% of the population correct:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 


import cv2
import sys, os.path, getopt
import numpy, random




def _usage():

    print
    print "cvbayes trainer"
    print
    print "Options:"
    print
    print "-m    --ham=     path to dir of ham images"
    print "-s    --spam=    path to dir of spam images"
    print "-h    --help     this help text"
    print "-v    --verbose  lots more output"
    print



def _parseOpts(argv):

    """
    Turn options + args into a dict of config we'll follow.  Merge in default conf.
    """

    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], "hm:s:v", ["help", "ham=", 'spam=', 'verbose'])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print(err) # will print something like "option -a not recognized"
        _usage()
        sys.exit(2)

    optsDict = {}

    for o, a in opts:
        if o == "-v":
            optsDict['verbose'] = True
        elif o in ("-h", "--help"):
            _usage()
            sys.exit()
        elif o in ("-m", "--ham"):
            optsDict['ham'] = a
        elif o in ('-s', '--spam'):
            optsDict['spam'] = a
        else:
            assert False, "unhandled option"

    for mandatory_arg in ('ham', 'spam'):
        if mandatory_arg not in optsDict:
            print "Mandatory argument '%s' was missing; cannot continue" % mandatory_arg
            sys.exit(0)

    return optsDict     




class ClassifierWrapper(object):

    """
    Setup and encapsulate a naive bayes classifier based on OpenCV's 
    NormalBayesClassifier.  Presently we do not use it intelligently,
    instead feeding in flattened arrays of B&W pixels.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassifierWrapper,self).__init__()
        self.classifier     = cv2.NormalBayesClassifier()
        self.data           = []
        self.responses      = []


    def _load_image_features(self, f):
        image_colour    = cv2.imread(f)
        image_crop      = image_colour[327:390, 784:926]        # Use the junction boxes, luke
        image_grey      = cv2.cvtColor(image_crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    features        = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(image_grey, 4, 0.02, 3)
        return features.flatten()


    def train_from_file(self, f, cl):
        features    = self._load_image_features(f)
        self.data.append(features)
        self.responses.append(cl)


    def train(self, update=False):
        matrix_data     = numpy.matrix( self.data ).astype('float32')
        matrix_resp     = numpy.matrix( self.responses ).astype('float32')
        self.classifier.train(matrix_data, matrix_resp, update=update)
        self.data       = []
        self.responses  = []


    def predict_from_file(self, f):
        features    = self._load_image_features(f)
        features_matrix = numpy.matrix( [ features ] ).astype('float32')
        retval, results = self.classifier.predict( features_matrix )
        return results




if __name__ == "__main__":

    opts = _parseOpts(sys.argv)

    cw = ClassifierWrapper()

    ham     = os.listdir(opts['ham'])
    spam    = os.listdir(opts['spam'])
    n_training_samples  = min( [len(ham),len(spam)])
    print "Will train on %d samples for equal sets" % n_training_samples

    for f in random.sample(ham, n_training_samples):
        img_path    = os.path.join(opts['ham'], f)
        print "ham: %s" % img_path
        cw.train_from_file(img_path, 2)

    for f in random.sample(spam, n_training_samples):
        img_path    = os.path.join(opts['spam'], f)
        print "spam: %s" % img_path
        cw.train_from_file(img_path, 1)

    cw.train()

    print
    print

    # spam dir much bigger so mostly unused, let's try predict() on all of it
    print "predicting on all spam..."
    n_wrong = 0
    n_files = len(os.listdir(opts['spam']))
    for f in os.listdir(opts['spam']):
        img_path    = os.path.join(opts['spam'], f)
        result = cw.predict_from_file(img_path)
        print "%s\t%s" % (result, img_path)
        if result[0][0] == 2:
            n_wrong += 1

    print
    print "got %d of %d wrong = %.1f%%" % (n_wrong, n_files, float(n_wrong)/n_files * 100, )
```

Right now I'm training it with a random subset of the spam, simply because there's much more of it and you should have a roughly equal amount of training data for each class.  With better curated data (e.g. always include samples from dawn and dusk when lighting is different) it would probably be higher.

Perhaps even a NormalBayesClassifier is the wrong tool for the job and I should experiment with motion detection across consecutive frames - but at least the Internet has an example to pick apart now.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that the amount of memory that it's trying to allocate is (720 * 1280) ^ 2 * 8. I think that might actually be the amount of memory that it needs.

I would expect a Bayesian model to let you make sequential calls to train(), so try resampling the size down, and then calling train() on one image at a time?

Comment: Alas I've tried something like that - calling train on only one datapoint results in:

    cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp:729: error: (-5) There is only a single class in function cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to note, In the latest OpenCV version you can need to create a NaiveBayseianClassifier like

```
import cv2

Classifier = cv2.ml.NormalBayesClassifier_create()
```

train the classifier as below, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE specifies how the data matrix is built i.e row wise or column wise [opencV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d7d/classcv_1_1ml_1_1StatModel.html#af96a0e04f1677a835cc25263c7db3c0c)

```
classifier.train(matrix_data, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, matrix_resp)
```